# Biblatex Chicago author-date system. Creating a hyperref for an only pagenumber citation when citing several references to the same source

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing, biblatex-chicago, chicago-style

In the *Chicago Manuel Of Style* when citing multiple times the same source but a different page the In-Text citation should be only the pagenumber in brakets.

According to the *Chicago Manuel Of Style* text should look like the following:

> Complexion figures prominently in Morgan’s descriptions. When Jasper compli­ ments his mother’s choice of car (a twelve-cylinder Mediterranean roadster with leather and wood-grained interior), “his cheeks blotch indignantly, painted by jealousy and rage” (Chaston 2000, 47). On the other hand, his mother’s mask never changes, her “even-tanned good looks” (56), “burnished visage” (101), and “air-brushed confidence” (211) providing the foil to the drama in her midst. (CMOS 2017, 905)

In my source code it would look like this:

> Complexion figures prominently in Morgan’s descriptions. When Jasper compli­ ments his mother’s choice of car (a twelve-cylinder Mediterranean roadster with leather and wood-grained interior), “his cheeks blotch indignantly, painted by jealousy and rage” (\cite[47]{MyKeyChaston2000}). On the other hand, his mother’s mask never changes, her “even-tanned good looks” (56), “burnished visage” (101), and “air-brushed confidence” (211) providing the foil to the drama in her midst.

And my preamble package for the *Chicago Manuel of Style* author-date system is:

> \usepackage[
> authordate,
> backend=biber,
> natbib,
> maxbibnames=99,
> ibidtracker=false,
> ]{biblatex-chicago}

Is there a way to tweak the \cite command to create a hyperref to the right bibliography entry (for example \cite[47]
{MyKeyChaston2000}) but only display the pagenumber (47)?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you'll want to load `biblatex-chicago` without giving `ibidtracker=false,`, since you actually want the CMoS "ibid." feature.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber,  maxbibnames=99]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite[382]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, 380) ipsum (381) dolor (382)]

This doesn't link the postnote though, if you insist on that you can try

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber,  maxbibnames=99]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {}%
    {\postnotewrapper%\setunit{\postnotewrapper}
     \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{postnote}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite[382]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber,  maxbibnames=99]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtoggle{cms@wasibid}
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\togglefalse{cms@wasibid}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@noibid}%
    {\blx@ibidreset%
     \usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{prenote}\AND\iffieldundef{postnote}}%
       {\blx@ibidreset%
        \usebibmacro{cite}%
        \PackageWarning{biblatex-chicago}%
          {Empty Ibidem citation}}%
       {\toggletrue{cms@inlineibid}%
        \global\toggletrue{cms@wasibid}}}}%
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}%
    {}%
    {\postnotewrapper%\setunit{\postnotewrapper}
     \iftoggle{cms@wasibid}
       {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{postnote}}}
       {\printfield{postnote}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite[382]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```